# DSP or signal/image/data processing jokes

Tags: image-processing, discrete-signals, reference-request, humor

Some other [StackExchange](http://stackexchange.com/)/[StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) sites are entertained with a certain level of humor or fun.  [What is your favorite “data analysis” cartoon?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/423/what-is-your-favorite-data-analysis-cartoon) is particularly worth  mentioning (IMHO)  this xkcd cartoon on causality and correlation (DSP folks know what I mean):

[image: xkcd: causality and correlation]

So [Is humor allowed in answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16496/is-humor-allowed-in-answers) I hope so, see for instance:

- StackOverflow: [What is your best programmer joke?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234075/what-is-your-best-programmer-joke)
- MathOverflow: [Do good maths jokes exist](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/1083/do-good-math-jokes-exist)
- SE.Stats (Cross Validated): [Statistics Jokes](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1337/statistics-jokes)
- SE.Stats (Cross Validated): [What is your favorite “data analysis” cartoon?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/423/what-is-your-favorite-data-analysis-cartoon)
- SE.Maths [Questions about math jokes](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68/questions-about-math-jokes)

Humor in signal processing or image processing does exist, albeit shallow, and narrow-spread. I have encountered it first (I had zero humor before) at the [ICASSP 2000](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/mostRecentIssue.jsp?punumber=6939) DSP humor exhibition in Istanbul, Turkey. The image below comes from [Humor in DSP by EURASIP](http://www.eurasip.org/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=103):

[image: Steepest descent in optimization]

So I believe that we deserve some `humor` and `joke` tags and actual lightness.
Go ahead!

Comment: I very much like the topic, I am wondering however if this thread is more appropriate in Meta (?). Similar to the `dsp-puzzle` tag, it would be nice to have a `dsp-humour` (?) tag. It will be challenging to formulate it as a question though (["Why are you dragging this chain?", "Have you tried pushing it?"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0Jv_XR6RMAI))

Comment: This is an appropriate comment. I will go on digging how it is handled on other SE sites. One suggestion: turn the joke into a genuine post on the underlying DSP theory, and move it to a community wiki?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

An airplane is leaving [Warsaw](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warsaw) (the capital of Poland), and gets caught in a terrible winter storm. The plane rolls, pitches and yaws. The crew is expecting the plane to crash or break up at any time. But one DSP student suddenly stands up and asks some passengers on the right aisle to move across the plane. Passengers are reluctant but the student insists. “Hurry, our fate depends on your move.” Most passengers quickly leap to the other side, and suddenly the plane stops shaking. The pilot, who had a DSP degree too,  enjoys calming everybody:

> "Thank you for the Poles who have moved to the left-half of the plane for stability."

[image: Filter stability: poles in left plane]

Additional references:

- [The Routh Stability Criterion](https://www.facstaff.bucknell.edu/mastascu/eControlHTML/Stability/Routh.htm)
- [Warsaw](http://www.um.warszawa.pl/en), Poland
- [Stability Revisited](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/fp/Stability_Revisited.html)

Another visual pun (dedicated to @MarcusMuller) is this chocolet decomposition:

[image: wavelet chocolet decomposition]

Comment: Duplicate? Delete one or the other. :-)

Comment: Double pole clicked at the origin I guess :)

Comment: Love that chocolate decomposition!

Comment: I had two cakes, one primal and one dual

Answer (score 10):

In high school math class I finally got the courage up to ask the cute and brainy girl at the front row out on a date. She just looked at me with a discouraging face and as she waved her hand face down horizontally from side to side. I asked her "What's that mean?", and she said "It's the Fourier Transform of this!" as she raised up her middle finger to me. After joining DSP.SE, I finally figured out what she was talking about.

[image: important FT]

[image: no luck]

Comment: Woof, woof, woof!

Answer (score 9):

Crazy Audio Fx ilustration lol

[image]

more:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Most 1D signals concepts illustrated in 2D. Nice

Answer (score 8):

More of a terrible visual pun:

[image]

The FFTiramisu.

Comment: I cannot accept it for ethical purposes, but let Cookey and Turkey algorithmics gods bless you

Comment: It was, indeed, blessed with deliciousness :)

Comment: I have added a terrible culinary pun similar to yours

Comment: @LaurentDuval awesome! Sadly, I can't double-upvote

Comment: I had two cakes with a different chocolate flavor, and obtained a dual-tree chocolet transform. Unfortunately, parts of my belly became redundant

Answer (score 6):

I personally also consider this very early XKCD to be a signal processing joke:

[[image: http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/fourier.jpg]

EDIT: While were doing early xkcd:

[image: poisson]

(both, of course, by Randall Munroe, CC-SA-Noncommercial)

Comment: The "Meouw" part  is TOO "time-based" to get credit for:)

Comment: Upvote the cat joke! The meouw-law compels you! (especially since the dynamic range for giving or not giving credit is pretty limited)

Comment: Upvoted is already done. Credits are in a different dimension

Comment: You must be kidding. Poisson (*Fisch*) and Cat totally cancel each other like scissors/paper/stone, albethy trilingual.

Comment: Ohhh! There's a whole class of jokes to be made about distributing fish!

Comment: And in the category of bilingual jokes, there's a lot of (rather lewd) potential in *leakage* translating to the same German word as *licking*.

Answer (score 6):

Sent to me by my friend Jerry Doty:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I met up with RBJ at a bar this weekend and he immediately wanted to get into deeper details of the Fourier Transform. I refused--- it's just too dangerous to drink an derive.

Comment: Especially when you are sliding

Comment: I worry about rectal leakage using a rectangular window.

Answer (score 4):

Ever wondered why there's "Live Aloha" bumper stickers?
Aloha is a remarkably unhealthy approach to vehicular traffic.

Answer (score 3):

```
  ___       __                           _      _   _   _   __
   |  |  | |       _|__|_ |\  /| |    | / \ |  / ` | \ / \ |  \
   |  |--| |-      _|__|_ | \/ | |    | `-. | |    |  |`-. |__/
   |  |  | |__      |  |  |    |  \__/  \_/ |  \_, |_/ \_/ |
             _          __       ___         __   __  _
       ,´\  | \ \    / |   |\  |  |  |    | |  \ |   / \
       |__| |  | \  /  |-  | \ |  |  |    | |__/ |-  `-.
       |  | |_/   \/   |__ |  \|  |   \__/  |  \ |__ \_/
               _________________________________
               EPISODE XI - FIXED POINT L33TNESS
               Guest script & sketch artist: mrl
                      INTRODUCING: ZEPHOD
               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
|(_)   o  ..Hi bram!                o ..Hi Phixedpoint zePh0d!
|     <&>                          <#>
|     /·\                          /P\ 

|(_)   o  ..Oh goodie!              o ..Cum here and i'll tell
|     <&\                          \#\  j00 all about my *HOT*
|     /·\                          /P\  adventures with mrl..

|(_)               crap.. o       __o ..Ha ha! You and your
|                        /&>        #> "fixed-point l33tness"!
|      ·                 / \       /P\          *END OF EP.11*
```

Comment: It misspells 1337N355! ;-)  My VW Beetle has the license place F34TUR3. :-)

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a [paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/149998) with Brian Lovell and Boualem Boashash about the Wigner-Ville time-frequency representation.  I'm not a fan of the Wigner-Ville for signal processing as I believe there are many better approaches to problems that it might solve.

To make this displeasure known but not obviously, I chose to encode it in the notation used in the paper.

[image: The Wigner-Ville is a wank.]

Comment: Well, this definitely had $\frac{\mathrm d\, F_u(n)}{\mathrm d\,n} >0 $ for me

Answer (score 2):

At the GNU Radio Conference:

> I'll skirt over scalloping losses here

Answer (score 2):

> I was going to tell a joke about the appendages of an absolutely normal cat, but it has a really fat tail.

<sup>[Source](https://mobile.twitter.com/dEnergy_dTime/status/1287395027073634306)</sup>

Comment: I was going to retweet your joke, but I now prefer to signal it

Answer (score 2):

Superheterodyne Receivers:

Compared to direct conversion, not that complex.

Answer (score 2):

I made this terrible visible pun for a shirt for myself, but then made it available for the benefit of a favorite software project of mine as [merchandise](https://gnuradio.myspreadshop.com/famous+constellations-A5d89f4bb2051762642237771?productType=444&sellable=ekYBx1d5JzHB8xYAx7bj-444%3A37cba8a0-23&appearance=4)

[image: Drawing Titled "Famous Constellations", showing text "Orion" next to the stellar constellation of Orion, Ursa Major (next to the constellation), Cassiopeia, but also terrble punny things like PSK Qudripartitus next to a constellation diagram of a QPSK, PSK Bipartitus Asynchronous next to a phase-unstable BPSK constellation, QAM Magnus…]

Comment: Since "stern" means star, isn't consternation?

Comment: bad synchronization is always cause for conSTERNation :)

Comment: (on a serious note: Constellation (as in "star pattern") is "Sternbild" (star image), but I'm having an incredibly hard time coming up with a pun that involves Phasenumtastung (tasten = to key -> Tastung = (noun) keying -> +um prefix -> "re-keying"; Phasen = phases), but that's the hardship of compounding languages: even while reading, the receiver does a lot that kind of seems to approximate a BCJR on the compound's meaning, so that puns on compound words quickly become awkward)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not ashamed I've decorated an institute hallway with this.

[image: An image with superimposed text. Image shows Ernie and Bert, from Sesame Street. Top: Ernie, could your illustrate source coding? Bottom: Sure, Bert: KRRKRKRKRKRKK…, a sound reminescent of noise you get when you just put an unfiltered On-of-keying data stream to a speaker. Hence, a pun. A terrible pun.]